# Can you sustain a spell multiple times per turn?

Tags: spells, magic, pathfinder-2e

For example, if I sustain the [Flaming Sphere](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=121) spell, I can use it to damage an opponent. Can I sustain it 3 times per turn, to deal damage 3 times?

Comment: This is being asked over in the [Forums](https://paizo.com/search?q=flaming+sphere&forum=v5748dmu0pw6x) a couple of places. Hopefully it will be FAQ'd.

Answer (score 14):

Mark Seifter, Designer, has stated on the [Paizo forums](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs42q8p?Can-Flaming-Sphere-be-used-more-than-once-per#28):

> We have it coming in the next errata batch. Sustain a given spell once per round only, unless the spell specifically encourages you to do so more than once like spiritual weapon.

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] if you need further guidance. I edited the answer to improve the format a bit but feel free to further [edit] or revert any of the changes. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: This is from a few years ago, before the 2nd _Core Rulebook_ printing that contained different changes to what Mark described here which also address the issue.

Answer (score 9):

### Yes

Nothing in [Sustain a Spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=73) prevents a character from Sustaining a spell multiple times in a turn.

However, *flaming sphere* and several other spells intended to provide once per turn benefits were updated to as part of the [Core Rulebook errata](https://paizo.com/pathfinder/faq).

> Several sustained spells are meant to provide once per turn benefits when they are sustained, not be used multiple times per turn. In ***flaming sphere***, *implosion, unfathomable song, impaling briars*, and *storm lord* add **"the first time you Sustain this Spell each round"**